# SQL - Left join to two tables returns nothing

Tags: mysql

The query I have is as follows.

```
SELECT A.ItemID, A.MSRP, A.SalesPrice, A.Cost, A.DiscountPercent,
       B.QuantityOnHand, B.QuantityAvailable, C.OrderRate, C.OrderQuantity
FROM item_info A
LEFT JOIN inventory_status B
   ON A.ItemID = B.ItemID
LEFT JOIN order_line C
   ON A.ItemID = C.OrderLineItemID
WHERE A.Name LIKE ?
AND C.OrderRate != 0
AND C.OrderQuantity != 0
ORDER BY C.OrderRate ASC, C.OrderQuantity ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Basically, the idea is to run a search for some item and retrieve its basic information, quantities in stock, and historical data.  Prior to modifying this query in order to get the historical data, it worked perfectly and simply gave me `null` for both `QuantityOnHand` and `QuantityAvailable` in the event that it had no entry in the `inventory_status` table, while the rest of its information would return normally.  However, trying to join to the third table no longer does this.  Now, nothing is returned.  Is there any way to modify this so that I get `null` for OrderRate and OrderQuantity in the event that no record for the item retrieved exists in the `order_line` table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to move the predicates

```
C.OrderRate != 0 AND 
C.OrderQuantity != 0
```

from `WHERE` to `ON` clause:

```
SELECT A.ItemID, A.MSRP, A.SalesPrice, A.Cost, A.DiscountPercent, 
       B.QuantityOnHand, B.QuantityAvailable, C.OrderRate, C.OrderQuantity
FROM item_info A
LEFT JOIN inventory_status B
   ON A.ItemID = B.ItemID
LEFT JOIN order_line C
   ON A.ItemID = C.OrderLineItemID AND 
      C.OrderRate != 0 AND 
      C.OrderQuantity != 0
WHERE A.Name LIKE ?
ORDER BY C.OrderRate ASC, C.OrderQuantity ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Otherwise, the `LEFT JOIN` operation becomes an `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Change this part

```
LEFT JOIN order_line C
ON A.ItemID = C.OrderLineItemID
WHERE A.Name LIKE ?
AND C.OrderRate != 0
AND C.OrderQuantity != 0
```

to this

```
LEFT JOIN order_line C
ON A.ItemID = C.OrderLineItemID
AND C.OrderRate != 0
AND C.OrderQuantity != 0
WHERE A.Name LIKE ?
```

Comment: this is correct but Giorgos' answer is better because he explained the reason - if you just give a code-only answer it's hard to learn from it